# SSRS 2012: Want new Page Each Time Value in Specific Column Changes

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, grouping

SSRS 2012: Want new Page Each Time Value in Specific Column Changes

I have a query that returns the result set. It returns all the values I want and I Grouping by specific column. Want new page each time the Group value in Location column changes.  So for Instance all the A's on one page, B's take 3 pages, New page for C's, etc

How do I set pagination for this?

Answer (score 0):

Click in the column you're grouping by.

At the bottom of your screen, you should see two boxes, 'Row Groups' and 'Column Groups'.

Right click your group and select `Group Properties...`.

Click the `Page Breaks` tab.

Check the box that says `Between each instance of a group`.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work.  What happens is that each row for each location becomes a page.  So I end up with 150 pages.

Comment: Do you have any grouping hierarchies above that?  What are your row/column groups?